# How to authenticate a user with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-security

I've set up the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` so that it redirects everything to the /login URL, however now I'm confused to as to how to grant authentication? I have a `User.java`, `UserRepository.java` and a `UserService.java`

I've read multiple articles on how to do basic authentication with Spring Boot. The only thing that they have in common is that they use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to redirect users to a login page. It seems there are various ways to implement logging in, I just want to use basic `UserController -> UserService -> UserRepo` way to retrieve a user along with his/her data. This is the code I have so far.

**Web security config**

```
    package com.flashcards.flashcard;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();


        } 
    }
```

**User.java**

```
    package com.flashcards.flashcard;

    import lombok.Data;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id; 
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

    @Data
    @Entity

    class User{
        private @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
        private String userName;
        private String password;
        private String passwordConfirm;
        @OneToMany
        private List<FlashCard> flashCards;

        User(String user, String pass, String passwordConfirm){
            this.userName = user;
            this.password = pass;
            this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
        }

        void appendCard(FlashCard card){
            flashCards.add(card);
        }
    }
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
    package com.flashcards.flashcard;


    public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
        public User getUser(String name, String p){}
        public void updateUser(){}
        public void deleteUser(){}
    }
```

**LoadDatabase.java,** initializes data for the web application.

```
    package com.flashcards.flashcard;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class LoadDatabase implements CommandLineRunner {


        private final FlashCardRepository flashcardRepository;
        private final UserRepository userRepository;

        @Autowired
        public LoadDatabase(FlashCardRepository flashcardRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
            this.flashcardRepository = flashcardRepository;
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

            this.userRepository.save(new User("user", "password", "password"));

        }
    }
```

Comment: tbh if you really want to understand authentication and authorization in spring security i really, really recommend the technical overview documentation. This will give you a really good understanding of the spring security classes and their role.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#technical-overview

Answer (score 1):

You can use `configure(HttpSecurity http)` to secure your endPoints. Consider that you have some endPoint as below.

```
/admin/newuser --> endPoint which can be access only by user with ROLE_ADMIN
/admin/users --> endPoint which can be access only by user with ROLE_ADMIN
/user/profile --> endPoint which can be access by user with ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN
```

To achieve this you have to add role field in your model which is saved in the database as *ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER (ROLE_ROLETYPE avoid small letters while saving it to database to avoid further error)*. You can add it as below in `configure()`.

```
.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
.antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
```

---

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

         http
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/login","/logout").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
         .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .formLogin()
         .loginPage("/login")
         .loginProcessingUrl("/login");      
    }
```

you can change `.anyRequest().authenticated()` to `.anyRequest().permitAll()` if you don't want to authenticated User for endPoints otherthan mentimed in .antMatchers()